# Number of nontrivial projection of a unital commutative C* algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Q.Can we construct a unital commutative C* algebra such that it admits exactly 5 non trivial projection ?

I can't conclude that answer. I only know  For some  C* algebra , I and O is the only projections. If we take K as a connected compact Hausdorff space , C(K) does not have projection other than the constant functions I and 0 .

Is there any C* algebra satisfying the above question mentioned requirement?

Comment: 5 might be tricky, because for a commutative unital C*-algebra, the only projections will be sums of projections onto connected components. A naive guess would be $C(X_1 \sqcup X_2 \sqcup X_3)$, then you have $p_1,p_2,p_3$ projection on to the $x_i$. But you can take sums of these (so I count 6). I don't think 5 is possible, but I'll think some more on it. Edit: Looks like Martin answered that it needs to be divisible by 2 when you get enough connected components!

Answer (score 2):

A unital commutative C$^*$-algebra is of the form $C(X)$ with $X$ compact Hausdorff. The projections are precisely the characteristic functions $1_E$. Since you need $1_E$ to be continuous, the set $E$ needs to be clopen, that is an open connected component.

Let $E_1,\ldots,E_m$ be the connected components of $X$. Now let's see what happens:

- $m=2$: here $X=E_1\cup E_2$, and the projections are $0,1_{E_1},1_{E_2},1$
- $m=3$: now $X =E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3$, and the projections are $0,1_{E_1},1_{E_2},1_{E_3},1_{E_1\cup E_2},1_{E_1\cup E_3},1_{E_2\cup E_3},1$, so the non-trivial projections are already six.
- $m>3$: the number of available projections will be greater than six. Actually one can figure out that the number of non-trivial projections is $2^m-2$.

It might be easier to see what's going on if you instead consider $A=\mathbb C^m$.

Comment: I didn't understand why we need characteristic function to be continuous .may be I'm missing soome knowledge. And can you please tell me how you are calculating the projections for m=2 or m=3. I mean if X=E1 U E2  U E3, how I could see the projection as like you have mentioned ?

Comment: For a function to be in $C(X)$, it has to be continuous: that's what the "$C$" means. As I said, for $1_E$ to be continuous you need $E$ to be a connected component. Did you find the projections in $\mathbb C^m$?

Comment: I have tried. But I still couldn't find the projections in $\mathbb{C}$^m.

Comment: Really? You cannot find for what values of $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ you get  $(x_1^2,\ldots,x_m^2)=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$?

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Sorry , I was mistakenly trying to do it other way.

Comment: Those values are obviously 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Next you need to convince yourself that $\mathbb C^m=C(\{1,\ldots,m\})$.

Comment: Sir , can you please tell me what will be the case if there's infinity many connected components .

Comment: Where? $\ \ \ $

Comment: I mean , what if X has infinity many connected components ?  Is a Hausdorff , compact , connected space  locally connected? I don't know it's locally connected or not . If is it , then I know there's could only be finite many connected components of X .

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Different spaces will have different number of connected components.

Comment: if we have infinitely many components in X , what will be the number of projections ? Is it infinite ?

Comment: I mean here if we put m = infinity , then the number of projections becoming infinity . Is it true always ?

Comment: Yes, of course. In $C(\{0\}\cup\{\tfrac1n:\ n\in\mathbb N\}$, you have the projections $\delta_0$ and $\{\delta_{1/n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and all their sums.

Comment: But sir , {1/n: n belongs to $\mathbb{N}$} is not open not closed , don't we need clopen subset in this case?

Comment: Just one set won't make a difference. Every set $\{\tfrac1n\} $ is clopen. And, by the way, it is open.

Comment: Okay.. sir what would I give argument for  the general case, that for infinite number of components we will ALWAYS get  infinite number of projections. I did understand the above example ,but failing to construct argument for general case.

Comment: I mean it's not always true that all the components are clopen ( for finite case it's true I know ). For that case what should I argue?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use the components which are not open.

Comment: Can you tell me how could I show then  there are infinitely many separation ( that is how  we can write  X as union of two cloopen set in infinitely many  way )?

Comment: You have me completely lost. What is $X$?

Comment: A normal topological space , with infinitely many components in this case.

Comment: I'm just trying to get 'clopen' component infinite in number . Sorry 

Comment: Not enough to answer. Even considering subsets of $[0,1]$, you could have $X=\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, and $C(X)$ is projectionless.  Or $C(\mathbb Q\cap[0,1/2]\cup\{3/4\})$, with one non-trivial projection. Or $C(\bigcup_n(1/(n^2+1),1/n^2))$, with infinitely many projections